# Valves in pizza box fell out does order matter if lapping

Tags: engine, motorcycle, valve, cylinder-head

I had my valves numbered in a pizza box for lapping and i lifted the pizza box up the wrong way and every valve fell to the floor. i can tell intake apart from exhaust easily because they look different. Im lapping and doing head work anyway. My question is after lapping valves will i have issues with wear conserning the valve guides that i would need to do work on. I also have all the springs caps shims and retainers numbered in ice cube trays so they are going back into their original places. The head is from an r6 from 2002 with over head cams that are chain driven

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Lesson: tie a label to each valve instead of relying on a pizza box.

Answer (score 4):

Lapping won't solve your issues. The only thing you can do is get the valves back in the right order or take it to the machine shop and get a valve job. The problem is, the valves are matched to the seat. If you don't have them in the right spot, you're going to have leaks. Lapping only takes off small amounts of material, which isn't going to be enough to get the valve and seat mated correctly.

Comment: What would it take to get the valves back in the right order. There are no machine shops within a 200 mile radius of the city i live in that does automotive work for liability issues.

Comment: @UserName - 16 valves and 16 holes? That's quite a lot of combinations. Seriously I wouldn't even know where to tell you to begin. Any which way it'd be a guess.

Comment: I found an automotive machine shop[ and they quoted me around 750 for a valve job and at least a three month wait before they could start. I could probably buy a used cylinder head on ebay for about 150 and lap those if they leak all the while selling my leftover empty cylinder head, springs, valves, retainers and caps. Thanks for your answer though i really appreciate your expertice i just dont think machining the head is within my budget.

Comment: @UserName - I think your idea of purchasing a used/complete head is a great idea as long as it is in good shape.